# Elegantly transporting IObservable through WCF

Tags: wcf, system.reactive

I have a WCF service whose underlying data sources are Observables.

Currently, in the top layer of the service I'm invoking client callbacks from inside the subscriptions to these observables (I subscribe the client once to all the data sources).

Client-side, the callbacks invoke OnNext on Subjects.

It works, but I'd like to be a bit more subtle (i.e. only subscribing server-end when client code subscribes to Observables etc.), and I'm hoping to find something (not sure what) to wrap all this boiler code elegantly.

I'm starting work now, but if anyone has any pointers, bits of pseudo code, or fully working Nuget packages, I'd be interested in checking them out.

Comment: I voted to close, just because it's so broad and opinionated. But have a look at this fully working app: https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/ReactiveTrader

Comment: @JamesWorld Perhaps he's asking about something like a [TCP Qbservable Provider](https://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TCP%20Qbservable%20Provider)?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I didn't get that. IQbservable doesn't get a lot of air-time! It's clever stuff (kudos on your implementation btw), but IMHO rarely do business requirements stack up against the complexity of doing it well when all factors are considered - usually the necessary flexibility is easily codified in a small number of constrained parameters. Ultimately, bridging Rx will always boil down to the equivalent of `OnNext` into a `Subject` though won't it?

Comment: I agree that `IQbservable<T>` is a bit esoteric, though I know of at least 2 web services that could have benefited greatly from it: an online survey service and a network monitoring service (who shall remain nameless), and Cortana of course :-). A `Subject` isn't necessarily required anyway; often you just want a *cold* observable that opens a socket and pushes data from a server, and that's how I interpreted the OP's question -- I think my provider addresses the OP's point about "boilerplate" code. However, I also see what you mean; perhaps the question is just too ambiguous and open-ended.

Comment: @JamesWorld, yes I realised that it was a bit too floppy a question. Currently I've resigned myself to exposing a Subscribe/Unsubscribe+callback for each Observable on the service side, and implementing a 'sort of' Subject on the client side which just has added 'What to do on subscribe/unsubscribe' constructor arguments which are invoked when client code subscribes to the 'subject'.

Comment: Found this too: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58a519ec-2beb-43b5-b62e-0f053c79a17c/wcf-call-back-with-rx?forum=rx